# Limit drive starts with function block diagram

Tags: timer, mechatronics, function-block-diagram

I have a drive (modulating fan) which needs to be interlocked and prevented from starting. The requirement is that:

> The drive is limited to 3 starts per hour with a minimum of 10 minutes between starts.

I am programming using function blocks diagrams. Some information to aid in your understanding of the function block diagram I created:

- Program flow follows the execution numbers on the function blocks
- Cyan lines show values of the integer short data type
- Black lines show binary values (0/1)
- References (small rounded rectangles with an alphanumeric identifier and no execution number) are used to *move* data without the need for connecting lines

Many of the blocks used are self-explanatory, however, the following information may be of use:

- `diss` function block - routes either `in1` or `in2` to `out` depending on `bse`. When `bse` equals 0, `in1` is used
- `ccob`/`ccos` depends on the `mode`. 1 = rising edge, 2 = falling edge
- `dvss` function block - outputs the min/max of the two inputs

Here is the function block diagram. I am interested in an alternate or more efficient methods to achieve the requirement.

I have exported my [loop diagram as an SVG](http://svgshare.com/s/306).

I have broken the function block diagram into three views:

[image: view 1]

---

[image: view 2]

---

[image: view 3]

Comment: Did you program this into a PLC, or is this an unproven design?

Comment: @Mast Yes, function block diagrams are developed and downloaded into PLCs. The code works as per the requirement.

Comment: Can you include the SVG into the question itself? As per the requirements for Code Review, at least the important parts of the code must be present in the question itself. Links can be used as support, but links shouldn't have to be followed to review the essence of the question.

Comment: @Mast SE doesn't accept displaying SVGs in the question body. "Failed to upload; not a valid image (jpeg, png, tiff, gif or bmp)".

Comment: True, but you could snip the SVG in smaller parts and convert those to a valid image format. It's not ideal, but the alternative is worse.

Comment: @Mast I will look into that now.

Comment: @Will you can use the SVG image in the question if you post it on a HTTPS enabled site. After doing this, you can get the _raw_ url, `http://svgshare.com/s/306.svg`, and can include it in the question by adding `[![][0]][0]`, followed with `[0]: url` at some point after it. With the current url it'd be `[0]: http://svgshare.com/s/306.svg`. Which doesn't work as svgshare doesn't allow HTTPS traffic.

Comment: @Peilonrayz I would if there was a reliable site offering hosting of SVGs. I have broken the drawing down into three bitmaps. However, I an encountering an error when I try to save my edit. See the Meta question.